fleek.co NextJS docker image version 18 possible?
I have a NextJS app, that I deploy to fleek. There it gets built and deployed. I recently changed something which requires a newer node version (version 18)
The deployment used node-16 and therefore ran into an error:

I tried to change to node version to 18 in the fleek deploy settings page:

This results in an error that it can not find the docker image:

I then found out you can specify it like this and will give the latest node version:
fleek/next-js

This then gives me the same error as initially, so it seems this also uses version 16. Is there a way to use node 18 here and get this running?

To update your Dockerfile to use a specific version of Node.js (version 20.13.1 in this case), you can follow these steps. Below is the improved Dockerfile:
# Use the base image for Next.js applications
FROM fleek/next-js:latest

# Remove any existing Node.js and npm binaries
RUN rm -rf /usr/local/bin/node\
           /usr/local/bin/nodejs\
           /usr/local/bin/npm

# Define the Node.js version to be installed
ENV NODE_VERSION=20.13.1

# Download and extract Node.js
RUN wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz &&\
    tar -xJf node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz &&\
    mv node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64/bin/* /usr/local/bin/ &&\
    rm -rf node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64 node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz

# Verify the Node.js installation
RUN node -v

# Set the entrypoint script
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]

# Default command to run Node.js
CMD ["node"]

Explanation:

Remove Existing Node.js and npm Binaries: Ensures any pre-installed versions are removed.
Set Node.js Version: Uses an environment variable for easy version updates.
Download and Install Node.js: Combines download, extraction, installation, and cleanup into a single RUN command to optimize the image.
Verify Installation: Checks the installed Node.js version.
EntryPoint and CMD: Sets the entrypoint script and default command.

This approach helps keep your Docker image clean, optimized, and ensures you're using the desired version of Node.js.
Happy fleeking :)
